# How to remove a section number in a beamer presentation?

Tags: beamer, frame-title

I'm using a custom beamer lay out for a presentation I'm giving, made by my school. However, the lay out forces me to use sections, so whenever I title my frame, I get

"0 Frame title"

However, I don't want to use sections and I just want to title my frames without a number being there, but I have no idea what I need to look for in the code to solve this.

Comment: This is not default beamer behaviour. We would need to see a [minimal working example (MWE)](https://tex.meta.stackexchange.com/q/228) that reproduces the problem in order to try to help you

Answer (score 1):

Found it myself when scanning the beamer theme again. There was some code

```
%head frametitle    
\setbeamertemplate{frametitle}
{
    \vspace{18pt}
    {\large\textbf{\thesection ~~ \insertframetitle}} 
    % section number -- frame title 
}
```

I deleted `\thesection ~~` and it worked!